# Writing a date from a pandas_datareader to database results in -1999

Tags: python, date, pandas, format, pandas-datareader

I have written a simple python application to read stock prices from google using the pandas_datareader and store them in the database. I find it strange that when I write the dataset the dates are correct however when I extract the date and use it in an update statement, the date is messed up. Here is my code (excluding import statements and logic) and results:

```
df = webd.DataReader('WTB.L', 'google', dtStart, dtEnd)
print(df.head())
```

```
              Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
Date                                              
2012-03-02  1687.0  1687.0  1672.0  1672.0  341944
2012-03-05  1666.0  1684.0  1660.0  1665.0  333824
```

```
lastPriceDateX = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].tail(1).item())
lastPriceDateY = lastPriceDateX
lastPriceDate = lastPriceDateY.strftime('%d-%m-%Y').isoformat()
print('Last Price Date {}'.format(lastPriceDate))
```

*Last Price Date 21-03-2017*

Looks good so far, the date format is exactly as I wanted it! Now I write the date  into the SQLITE database: date is stored as -1999

The dataset is written to SQLite database, this has the correct date format:

"12667" "2017-03-16 00:00:00"   "WTB.L" "3926.0"    "3936.0"    "3882.0"    "3909.0"    "441329"
"12668" "2017-03-17 00:00:00"   "WTB.L" "3908.0"    "3926.0"    "3892.0"    "3903.0"    "642291"
"12669" "2017-03-20 00:00:00"   "WTB.L" "3907.0"    "3917.0"    "3883.32"   "3916.0"    "175681"
"12670" "2017-03-21 00:00:00"   "WTB.L" "3921.0"    "3926.0"    "3888.0"    "3914.0"    "315763"

Code to write this dataset:

```
df.to_sql('tblStockPricesGoogle', conn,
          if_exists='append', index=False,
          index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None)
```

I could write a python function to take the latest date from the prices table and write it to the last price. However, I would like to understand why this date prints correctly but it does not write to the database correctly.

Thank you all very much.

---

More code:

```
#Gets data from google.
    try:
        print('Try')
        df = webd.DataReader('WTB.L', 'google', dtStart, dtEnd)
        print(df.head())
        df.insert(0,"Symbol", sy)

        df = df.reset_index()

        if df.empty :
            print('DataFrame is empty. There could be various issues. No updates.')

        else :
            print(df.head(1))
            print("Starting update:")

            #Call update function and pass dataframe.

            if sql3.saveDFtoSQL(df):
                #update table with last price, date, updated date etc.

                index is also returned.
                lastPrice = df['Close'].tail(1).item()
                lastPriceDateX = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].tail(1).item())
                lastPriceDateY = lastPriceDateX
                lastPriceDate = lastPriceDateY.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
                print("Updated {} prices, task done!".format(sy))
                print('Last  Price {}'.format(lastPrice))
                print('Last Price Date {}'.format(lastPriceDate))
                                    lastUpdate = dt.date(today.year,today.month,today.day).isoformat()
                print('LastUpdate attribute:',lastUpdate)
                sql3.updateListLastUp(sy,lastUpdate,lastPrice,lastPriceDate)


def updateListLastUp(symbol,date,lastPrice,lastPriceDate):  

    try:    
        strUpdate = 'UPDATE tblList SET lastUpdate="{}", LastPrice={},LastPriceDate={}, GetData=0 WHERE Ticker="{}"'.format(date,lastPrice,lastPriceDate,symbol)
        conn = sq3.connect(sql_file)
        conn.execute(strUpdate)
        conn.commit()
        return 'Done'

    except sq3.Error as er:

        print('Failure to update DataSet:', er)
        return er.tostring()
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this using SQLite. Which database system are you using?

Comment: Hi Bernie, thank you for your reply. I have added some more code. I am using SQLite too. Basically writing the df to the DB has no issues. The issue seems to occur after reading the date from the df (lastPriceDateX = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].tail(1).item()), lastPriceDateY = lastPriceDateX, lastPriceDate = lastPriceDateY.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')) and writing it to the DB using the function def updateListLastUp(symbol,date,lastPrice,lastPriceDate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
strUpdate = 'UPDATE tblList SET lastUpdate="{}", LastPrice={},LastPriceDate={}, GetData=0 WHERE Ticker="{}"'.format(date,lastPrice,lastPriceDate,symbol)
```

You're using string interpolation (a big faux pas as it's insecure as well as leads to surprising results if values aren't escaped appropriately) to construct your query string, so what the DB engine sees is "2017-03-15" which is interpreted as 2017 - 3 - 15 and calculates the value which is 1999 etc...

All your problems will go away if you use query parameters, eg:

```
strUpdate = 'update tblList set lastUpdate=?, lastPrice=?, lastPriceDate=?, GetData=0 where Ticker=?'
# ...
conn.execute(strUpdate, (date, lastPrice, lastPriceDate, symbol))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this later on at home.

Comment: Thanks so much the problem was solved with quotes \'{}\'. Interesting Stuff.

Comment: @Thames you don't want to be using quotes either... What's wrong with using query parameters as I've shown? Using quotes -- at best it'll break if someone puts a quote in the data... At worse they can alter the query. Why not be safe and robust?

Comment: Thats a good point. This is not a real application but a learning experience. So thank very much for your explanation. I will update my notes and code. Thank you very much.